# creating a course registration form with paypal payment

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I want to create a page that lists class, allows the user to choose a course + fill out their name and email, lets the user pay with paypal and if they paid the form writes the data to a database.

I know how to make an HTML and PHP form with the required fields, I know how to write data to a database, I researhed how to create a paypal business account to accept payments, but how do I write the form data to the database AFTER the paypal page?  The browser is redirected to paypal's site for the payment isn't it?.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK34c.jpg
how can I keep variables from page 1 and use them on page 3 to write to the database?

Comment: There is also a `custom_id` you can pass to paypal during the `create` & redirect, which they return back to you when you `get` the order details using their return token. You could store all your custom variables to a db row, identified by that `id`... so you can then retrieve those variables on return; If you do not want to rely on `$_SESSION` variables (which may vanish if a user takes too long on paypal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend implementing this server-side checkout pattern: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

API calls happen on your server to set up and capture the transaction: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

When the API call to capture returns success, that is when you can immediately write the successful registration record in your database, and show the confirmation to the user.

Comment: it looks like I should use a combination of @IncrredibleHat 's comment and your answer.  I will use the code from your first link (although I do not see where to set the amount paypal is going to charge, so the value is defaulting to $0.01) and I will store the rest of the variables to `custom_id` for storage from page 1 during page 2 so that they can be reused on page 3 but I do not see where to set that either.  Do you know the answers to either of those questions so that I can use this answer?

Comment: The problem with storing data in $_SESSION and retrieving them after payment completion is that the customer is not guaranteed to return or trigger client-side code after a payment is captured. Only a server-side integration will guarantee code execution and storing records to a database on payment capture. A server-side integration does not need to store data in `custom_id` either.  The amount would be set in the transaction creation API call.

Comment: When a user clicks the pay with paypal button can I just put the values into `custom_id`?  If that variable is sent to the redirect page after the the charge is completed that solves the problem.  Does it work like that?  It looks like yes it does work like that from the above comment but I am not sure: "There is also a custom_id you can pass to paypal during the create & redirect, which they return back to you when you get the order details using their return token."

Comment: Redirects are not guaranteed to happen after a charge is completed. That is why a server API-based capture should be used.

Comment: thank you, I will use the generated paypal button to capture the current transaction